# Whether to do a NULL check in test cases if static analysis is enabled?

Tags: java, unit-testing, static-analysis, findbugs

Our project have static analysis enabled, and, when it comes to testing, we starting to worry if we should test for NULL check or anything that may already be tested by the static analysis.

Should I still test for those stuff?

E.g. For method:

```
@RegEx("bla.*bla") 
public static String bar(@Nonnull Foo par1)
```

Should we have test this:

```
assertTrue(Pattern.matches(XXX.bar(someFoo)));
```

Then test for the NPE thrown if null is passed in?

EDIT: We are using Findbugs, but I think the problem also applies to other static code analsis tools.

Comment: Which static analyzer is being used? Does it raise a warning if it cannot prove that the result satisfies the contract set by the annotation (this is ok, but has possible false positives), or only when it can prove the result definitely cannot satisfy the contract (not ok, as it may have false negatives)?

Comment: It's Findbugs. I'll added the tag. However I don't know the very details about its mecanhism., but I guess it's the first one. @HairyFotr

Answer (score 0):

The static analyzers will help you find the code paths that are likely to trigger NPE. FindBugs does analysis *mostly* scoped to individual method.

If you annotate your parameter with `@Nonnull` for commonly used API, you are definitely helping the analyzer (FindBugs).

Testing for NPE doesn't seem to bring any value. I would see value if this was a public API (important API) and the null pointer is properly handle (i.e. : with **`IllegalArgumentException`**).
This is obviously an opinion. There is no truth about the level of testing.